# My System.currentTimeMillis() method calls are not registering properly. I don't understand why they stay at 0.0

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class tester {

    static public class LinkedList {

        Node head; // head of list
        Node sorted;
        int size;

        // Linked list Node.
        // This inner class is made static
        // so that main() can access it
        public class Node {

            Object data;
            Node next;

            Node() {

            }

            // constructor
            Node(Object data) {
                this.data = data;
                next = null;
            }

            // constructor
            Node(Object data, Node n) {
                this.data = data;
                next = n;
            }

        }

        public void addFirst(Object d) {
            head = new Node(d);
            size++;

        }

        public void addLast(Object d) {
            Node temp = head;
            while (temp != null) {
                temp = temp.next;
            }

            temp = new Node(d,null);
            size++;
        }
        int getSize() {
             return size;
        }

        boolean isSorted() 
        {  
            if (head == null) 
                return true; 

            // Traverse the list till last node and return 
            // false if a node is smaller than or equal 
            // its next. 
            for (Node t = head; t.next != null; t=t.next) 
               if ((int)t.data <= (int)t.next.data) 
                    return false; 
            return true; 
        }  

          void InsertionSort()  
            { 
                // Initialize sorted linked list 
                sorted = null; 
                Node current = head; 
                // Traverse the given linked list and insert every 
                // node to sorted 
                while (current != null)  
                { 
                    // Store next for next iteration 
                    Node next = current.next; 
                    // insert current in sorted linked list 
                    sortedInsert(current); 
                    // Update current 
                    current = next; 
                } 
                // Update head_ref to point to sorted linked list 
                head = sorted; 
            }
            void sortedInsert(Node newnode)  
            { 
                /* Special case for the head end */
                if (sorted == null || (int)sorted.data >= (int)newnode.data)  
                { 
                    newnode.next = sorted; 
                    sorted = newnode; 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    Node current = sorted; 
                    /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
                    while (current.next != null && (int)current.next.data < (int)newnode.data)  
                    { 
                        current = current.next; 
                    } 
                    newnode.next = current.next; 
                    current.next = newnode; 
                } 
            } 



        public void MergeSort() {
            Queue q = new Queue();
            int count = 0;
            int[] sublist1 = null;
            int[] sublist2 = null;
            int[] tempList = null;
            // Node cur = head;
            for (Node cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.next) {
                LinkedList newList = new LinkedList();
                newList.addFirst(cur.data);
                q.enqueue(newList);
            }
            while (q.size > 1) {
                sublist1[count] = (int) q.dequeue();
                if (q.size >= 1) {
                    sublist2[count] = (int) q.dequeue();
                }
                Arrays.sort(sublist1);
                Arrays.sort(sublist2);

                tempList = merge(sublist1, sublist2);

            }
            q.enqueue(tempList);

        }

        public int[] merge(int[] a, int[] b) {

            int[] answer = new int[a.length + b.length];
            int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

            while (i < a.length && j < b.length)
                answer[k++] = a[i] < b[j] ? a[i++] : b[j++];

            while (i < a.length)
                answer[k++] = a[i++];

            while (j < b.length)
                answer[k++] = b[j++];

            return answer;
        }

    }

    static class Queue {
        int front, rear, size;
        int capacity;
        Object array[];

        // constructor
        public Queue() {
            front = 0;
            rear = 0;
            size = 0;
        }

        // constructor
        public Queue(int capacity) {
            this.capacity = capacity;
            front = this.size = 0;
            rear = capacity - 1;
            array = new Object[this.capacity];

        }

        boolean isFull(Queue queue) {
            return (queue.size == queue.capacity);
        }

        boolean isEmpty(Queue queue) {
            return (queue.size == 0);
        }

        void enqueue(Object newList) {
            if (isFull(this))
                return;
            this.rear = (this.rear + 1) % this.capacity;
            this.array[this.rear] = newList;
            this.size = this.size + 1;
        }

        Object dequeue() {
            if (isEmpty(this))
                return Integer.MIN_VALUE;

            Object item = (int) this.array[this.front];
            this.front = (this.front + 1) % this.capacity;
            this.size = this.size - 1;
            return item;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList A = new LinkedList(); 
        LinkedList A2 = new LinkedList();

        int ramdomListSize = 20000;
        for(int i = 0; i < ramdomListSize; i++) {
            int randomInt = (int)(Math.random() * 3000000);
            A.addLast(randomInt);
            A2.addLast(randomInt);
        }

        //measure the time cost of merge sort
        double then = System.currentTimeMillis();
        A.MergeSort();
        double now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time cost in milliseconds for mergesort " + (now - then));
        System.out.println(A.isSorted()); //verify that your merge sort implementation works.
        System.out.println("Size of list A is: " + A.getSize());

        //measure the time cost of insertion sort
        then = System.currentTimeMillis();
        A2.InsertionSort();
        now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time cost in milliseconds for insertionsort " + (now - then));
        System.out.println(A2.isSorted() ); //verify that your insertion sort works.
        System.out.println("Size of list A2 is: " + A2.getSize());    
    }//end of main 
}
```

Expected output:

```
Time cost in milliseconds for mergesort: 37.0 
true 
Size of list A is: 20000 
Time cost in milliseconds for insertionsort: 660.0
true 
Size of list A2 is: 20000
```

My Output:

```
Time cost in milliseconds for mergesort: 1.0
true
Size of list A is: 20000
Time cost in milliseconds for insertionsort: 0.0
true
Size of list A2 is: 20000
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `InsertionSort()` doesn't do anything.

```
 Node current = head;
 while (current != null) {
       ....
 }
```

You never assign `head` field, so it is always **null** and the loop is never executed.

The only assignment to `head` is done in `addFirst()` method which is never called.

Comment: I say "head = sorted; " at the end of the method.

Comment: That doesn't really help, cause "current = head" is at the beginning of the method. Just step through the code with debugger.

Comment: Plus one for previous comment.  @Freddy you need to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a field `Node current` to keep track of the last Node object.
Your method `addLast(Object d)` does not add the object to the list. Storing a different object in a variable does not affect the previously stored object so `temp = new Node(d,null);` will only change value of the variable `temp`.
The method should be like this

```
public void addLast(Object d) {
    if (current != null) {
        current.next = new Node(d,null);
        current = current.next;
    }
    else {
        head = new Node(d, null);
        current = head;
    }
    size++;
}
```

Your implementation of merge sort is also incorrect. `addFirst` should store previous `head` before updating and make the `next` field of the new head point to the old one. `sublist1` and `sublist2` are always `null` and `count` always remains 0. If you want to sort using merge sort, `Arrays.sort` should not be used because it uses quick sort for primitive types like `int`. Check out the correct implementation of merge sort [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/).